# Finding special form for integral binary cubic form

Tags: nt.number-theory, invariant-theory

Let $f(x,y)=px^3+3qx^2y+3rxy^2+sy^3$, $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$, be an integral binary cubic form. Under what conditions is $f$ equivalent to a form $g(x,y)=t x^3+3u x^2y+3v xy^2+w y^3$ with $u=v$?

Here equivalent means that there exists $A\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\mathrm{det(A)}}g((x,y)\cdot A)$.

This is not always possible: If $u=v$ then the discriminant $D(g)$ is given by
$$D(f)=(u^2-tw)^2-4u^2(u-t)(u-w).$$
One can show, that, depending on whether $u^2-tw$ is even or odd, we have $D(g)\equiv 1\mod 4$ or $D(g)\equiv 0,4\mod 16$ (in general the discriminant is always $\equiv 0,1\mod 4$). In particular, $f$ cannot be brought into the required form if $D(f)\equiv 8,12\mod 16$, e.g. for $f(x,y)=2x^3+3xy^2$. But what can be said if $D(f)\equiv 1\mod 4$ or $D(f)\equiv 0,4\mod 16$?